# Calculating the length of an array in haskell - non exhaustive patterns error

Tags: haskell, non-exhaustive-patterns

I've searched around on here and on the net in general and I can't find anything that seems to be answering this question. I've only just starting playing around with Haskell for a module at university and I'm having an issue defining a function to calculate the length of an array (the pre-existing length function essentially).

In my lecture notes the function is given as:

```
let len [] = 0
let len (h:t) = 1 + len t
```

This makes sense to me, it doesn't seem to be missing anything and I've seen something very similar posted elsewhere as well, but in GHCi it's throwing a "Non-exhaustive patterns" error and I can't for the life of me figure out why.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is two declarations, the second of which shadows the first.

You need to declare `len` as one function with two clauses. In GHCi, you can do that like this:

```
:{
let len [] = 0
    len (h:t) = 1 + len t
:}
```

the `:{ ... :}` form lets you enter multi-line declarations as you would in a `*.hs` file.

```
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loading package ghc-prim ... linking ... done.
Loading package integer-gmp ... linking ... done.
Loading package base ... linking ... done.

Prelude> let len [] = 0
Prelude> let len (h:t) = 1 + len t -- this shadows the earlier len
Prelude> len [1, 2, 3]
*** Exception: <interactive>:3:5-25: Non-exhaustive patterns in function len 
    -- exception because the new len doesn't handle an empty list

Prelude> :{
Prelude| let len [] = 0
Prelude|     len (h:t) = 1 + len t
Prelude| :}
Prelude> len [1, 2, 3]
3
Prelude>
```